# How I can get link to specific test launch in ReportPortal?

Tags: reportportal

I want link to last execution to be in letter sent by Jenkins after tests execution. How I can get this link?

Comment: is it freestyle job?

Comment: yes, it's freestyle job

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, previously your question was tagged with Jenkins?

Comment: unfortunately no, you are mistaken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some plugin for Jenkins which does exactly what you ask for. 
https://github.com/reportportal/plugin-jenkins
It's a quite outdated, but you are free to submit issue